# Set MSBuild default parameters when building locally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Is there a way to set a default set of parameters for `MSBuild` to use every time i build locally using `Ctrl + Shift + B`. I want to append a parameter like `/p:MyParameter` to the MSBuild call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *build locally* what do you mean with that exactly? Build in VS but not on the commandline? Locally on your computer only? ...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what parameters you want to pass and how will those be used by your project solution. But if those parameters are ought to be used by your project solution then you can create a [PropertyGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4w159bs.aspx) element and use it within your project at the time when VS builds your solution. Refer this [tutorial](http://thomasardal.com/msbuild-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the scenario is the following: you want to use some MsBuild variable values when debugging on your local machine, but don't want to use them in production.

- Add the following directive to the Visual Studio project or `.targets` file:

```
<Import Project="User.targets" Condition="Exists('User.targets')"/>
```

- Create the `User.targets` file - example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyProperty>Value</MyProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

- Exclude this file from Git/Mercurial repository.
- Close and restart Visual Studio.

Warning: when you change the referenced file, the changes may not take effect immediately; for them to take effect, either close and restart Visual Studio, or change the time of last change ("[touch](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch/764716)") on the solution file to force Visual Studio to reload it.